# \sidebar doesn't respect geometry's bottom margin

Tags: memoir, geometry

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{geometry, lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \newgeometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm, inner=1cm, outer=0.618\textwidth}

    \sidebar{\lipsum}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

The text in the margins only goes to where `memoir` had formerly placed the margins (you can verify this by commenting the `\newgeometry` line). I know that `geometry` and `memoir` together is not necessarily the best idea, but I really want the easy per-page geometry that `geometry` offers.

How do I get `\sidebar` to use `geometry`'s margins? (or how do I change per-page margins with `memoir`?)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The problem is that the sidebar doesn't respect `geometry`'s _bottom_ margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the `\sidebar` is set to `\textheight` when the class is loaded. And, of course, a change in the geometry is accompanied with a change in `\textheigth` that doesn't transfer to the `\sidebar`. You can correct for this by resetting the `\sidebar` height to `\textheight`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{geometry, lipsum}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm, inner=1cm, outer=0.618\textwidth}
\setsidebarheight{\textheight}
\sidebar{\lipsum}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which is why using the build in `memoir` interface for the layout might be a better idea.